# Why can't I get the href attribute of an element where as I can click on it using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, onclick, href

I see that many people have the reverse problem, but mine is this:

I have this webelement and when I use `element.click()` it redirects me to a website (the element has a link)

When I use `element.get_attribute('href')` I get None and I even tried to use a javascript to check for attributes of element, but it only has a class attribute.

Is there a way for me to get this link without clicking on the element?

From chrome inspection of elements in the webpage we have:

```
<div "element.class">
    <a href='link_that_i_want'>
```

Comment: you didn't add URL for this page so I can't check it but click may run JavaScript code and `href` can be inside JavaScript code - so it doesn't have to be as attribute in element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [href](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_href.asp) attribute

The *`href`* attribute specifies the URL of the page the link goes to.

Example:

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a>
```

The *`href`* attribute can be used on the following elements:

- *`<a>`*
- *`<area>`*
- *`<base>`*
- *`<link>`*

---

### [onclick](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp) event attribute

The *`onclick`* event attribute executes a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) when a button is clicked. The *`onclick`* attribute fires on a mouse click on the element.

Example:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

---

### Conclusion

Possibly the desired element have the *`onclick`* attribute instead of the *`href`* attribute.

Comment: for me to get that "a" element which variant should I use of "find_element_by_name" ?

Comment: @hellofriends If it is an `<a>` tag, order of preference should be, _linkText_, _partialLinkText_, _Css_ and then _XPath_.